# Is it possible to use Z coordinate to make android game compatible on multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

Drawing 2D graphics request only two coordinates and by default Z coordinate is 0. Is it possible to use that Z coordinate to adjust graphics sizes. Lets say for larger screens I set Z to be 0 but when screen is small (ldpi) i set z to be lets say -5 units and whole graphics fits into the screen. Is it good practice? Is it even possible to do like that?

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your graphics to the screen size (and rotation) you should adjust the opengl viewport size.

Not sure what you exactly plan to do with the z-coordinate, but it doesn't look like a good way for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you plan to use the z coordinate to zoom in or zoom out so that the scene fits correctly into the screen. It is valid point, you can easily do that by "hacking" the projection matrix that way. The only drawback I truly see is that you need to send down your pipeline one more coordinate for each vertex. Would be much easier to just set a global scaling factor which is stored either in the modelview-projection matrix or passed to the vertex shaders.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd want to add a "fake" depth to your 2D app ?

- With an orthographic projection (used in most of the 2D rendering world), it would be completely useless.
- With a perspective projection, it would surely lead to many subpixel glitches when the texture minification will occur, or blurring in case of magnification.

You could resize your sprites or - better - you could create a set of baked sprites of different sizes.

Comment: Don't agree with the second bullet point. Same problem applies to *any* scaling algorithm, and *every* android applications has to deal with those. You don´t get to keep a 1:1 image:hardware pixel ratio if you have to target anything from 320x240 to full hd and beyond.

Comment: I only emphasized it would cause min/mag artifacts, I didn't reject this possible - and probable - solution.

Comment: Most of the apps I've been working on used big-sized sprites (targeting the iPad screen format). An edge-preserving algorithm was applied at loading time to downscale them to the device screen size.

Comment: Interesting. By edge-preserving, do you mean classic image processing "preserving visual edges in the image data", or do you mean "respecting the individual sprite boundaries within the larger texture" (a common 2D game problem)?

Comment: I meant indeed a very classic edge-preserving downscale on individual sprites. The case of sprite sheets would need some image morphology nerdiness or a defined size for each sprite to prevent the filter to process unrelated sprites (or to hire an intern to draw nice boundaries over EACH sprite !)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is (and i mean no disrespect) that you know little about 2D rendering and came up with this idea. Actually is not that bad, it's a good first approach, but things are quite polished in the area. You should stick to the standard way of dealing with it, unless you really know what you are doing.

Standard way is to use projection matrices (or cameras in a higher level of abstraction). When using projections you define your "world coordinates". The projection maps your world to the GL viewport (usually the hole screen), so no matter the device screen size, you always show the same portion of the world. Note you'll have to deal with stretching.

I don't know if I'm really answering your question. This is not really what you asked, but what i think you wanted to ask. You shouldn´t bother with z-components if used an Orthographic projection (which is typical for 2D).

Comment: You are quite right. Of course, you noticed I didn't post any thing on the answers because, well, I don't actually know what you are speaking of. I have some experience  in 2D programming but not with OpenGL. It is completely new to me and it is really hard to get it all in my had. I got used to draw handler, canvas and UI that trigger some functions, which is similar here but with lots of addition that is required to know. I am getting an image of what you are speaking now but still need some more time to understand how things work.
Thanks for directions.